# jQuery to get the HTML code on right click

Tags: jquery, onclick, jquery-events

I am using jQuery and I need to get the HTML code of any element on which the user right clicks. The jsfiddle has the sample. I don't have IDs in the HTML code

```
JSFiddle is here
```

```
<div id="container">
  <p>Click Area 1</p>
  <p>Click Area 2</p>
  <div>
     Click area 3<br/>
     <a href="#">Click Area 4</a><br/>
     <a href="#">Click Area 5</a><br/>
  </div><br/>
   <div id="codewidget" ></div><br/>
</div>
```

How can I go about getting the HTML content and print it on the codewidget? I tried but I am kind of new to this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple problems

1. jQuery library was not selected in the jsfiddle
2. id `code widget` cannot have space
3. `$('#container').click(` was missing `$`

Try

```
<div id="container">
    <p>Click Area 1</p>
    <p>Click Area 2</p>
    <div>
        Click area 3<br/>
        <a href="#">Click Area 4</a><br/>
        <a href="#">Click Area 5</a><br/>
    </div><br/>
    <div id="codewidget" ></div><br/>
</div>
```

then

```
$('#container').click(
    function(e){ 
        //prevent any click
        e.preventDefault();
        //get the id of the selector
        var s = e.target.outerHTML;
        $("#codewidget").text(s);
    }
);
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/5zkKj/)

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply! When i click on Click Area 4, it gives the entire html then <a href="#"> Click Area 4</a><br/>. How can I just show the html content of what i clicked?

Comment: Sorry Arun. I think I made you confused as I wasn't clear. What i was saying is, when i click "Click Area 4" i want the html code of that particular code. Which is '<a href="#">Click Area 4</a><br/>'. The previous one you showed had it in a way that showed the entire container html codes. So that was what i was referring to. My apologies!

Comment: Tq, this is what i meant. Thank you for being very helpful.

Comment: Wasn't the question about doing this on a right click? This works great for a left click, but I think the OP wanted a right click.

Comment: @TKKocheran looks like the OP is not sure about that since he/she has accepted the answer

Answer (score 1):

@arun P Jony's code

change it like below this will give the html

```
$('#container').click(
    function(e){ 
        //prevent any click
        e.preventDefault();
        //get the id of the selector
        var s = e.target.outerHTML;
        $("#codewidget").html(s); <!-- change it to html instead of text
    }
);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but with $("#codewidget").html(s) it gives the exact copy of the items that i clicked. I am not looking for. But thumbs up for your attempt to answer as it is a different technique for some other use.